# Azure table storage unable to parse correct Date from Java

Tags: java, date, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I am following Azure sample to send data from java to Azure table storage. All the data is being transferred as expected but java.util.date type property is not reflecting properly. below is my Entity class

```
public class AzureDbEntity extends TableServiceEntity {
             public AzureDbEntity(String type, String id) 
             {
                    this.partitionKey = type;
                    this.rowKey = id;

             }

             public AzureDbEntity()
             {

             }
             Date SenderSentAt;
            String Sender;
             public Date getSentAt() {
                    return this.SentAt ;
                }

             public void setSentAt(Date SenderSentAt) {
                 this.setTimestamp(SenderSentAt);
                    this.SentAt = SenderSentAt;
                }
              public String getSender() {
                    return this.Sender;
                }
              public void setSender(String Sender) {
                    this.Sender = Sender;
                }
}
```

I am setting SentAt and Sender values in below code

```
entity.setSentAt(new Date());
entity.setSender(data.Sender);
batchOperation.insertOrReplace(entity);
```

Application logs shows that i have sent following date time

```
Sun Sep 16 23:41:30 GST 2018
```

but when I check azure table storage. it shows me the following value

```
Sun 16 Sep 2018 16:00:18 GMT
```

The difference between GST and GMT is 4 hours but Azure is showing more than 7 hours difference after converting GST to GMT.
I am also setting TimeStamp in java code and it is appearing as expected with 4 hours difference in GMT(Sun 16 Sep 2018 19:41:31 GMT)

Comment: So you would have expected Sun 16 Sep 2018 19:41:30 GMT? GST as very many other time zone abbreviarions is amniguous. I take it that you intend Gulf Standard Time?

Comment: Which property you sent GST date time? SentAt?Or Sender? You mean you sent GST time and it convered by azure table storage and it differs the standard time?

Comment: GST stands for Gulf Standard Time which is GMT+4. We are sending SentAt as GST. Azure table storage convert it to GMT for storage but the difference between sent and stored time is around 7 hours. The expected stored value is Sun 16 Sep 2018 19:41:30 GMT